# Adding image in HTML website not working

Tags: html, image

I'm trying to create a website for my Mum's garden design service. I am trying to add a photo of her logo using a link. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/13MbE.png). I will show you the part that I need assistance with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/13MbE.png)">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Review the proper syntax for [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img). You might find the [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Example_1_Alternative_text) useful.

Comment: Also see [URL vs SRC](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/url-vs-src).

Answer (score 2):

When linking an image, there is no (url) needed before your actual url. The (url) is only used for background images in CSS.

img src:

```
<img src = "https://i.imgur.com/Ug8Tx59.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ug8Tx59.png">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add the image in css or html.

In HTML:

```
<div id="logo">
  <img src="http://..." alt="...optional...description" >
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
#logo {
  background-image: url("http://...");
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have an image link:

```
<a href="/"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ug8Tx59.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t understood what exactly you want to do. You want to add this photo from imgur to the screen-display of the site, or you want this photo to be your site logo? (This logo that is at the top of the browser)
If you want the first, (display the logo to the screen) you have to do-write this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> </title>
</head>

    <body>
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Ug8Tx59.png">
    </body>

</html>
```

For the second option, (display this imgur logo at the top of your webpage, on the browser, just comment me and I’ll write you the code and explain it to you.